# Multiple images without spacing

Tags: graphics

I have this picture and I want to create a single page document with this picture repeated eight times.

[image: single picture]

The image should have a border (light gray), it should have exactly 13cm of width and there should be no space between the pictures.

So far, my best result was this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

%\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.25}
\definecolor{LightGray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[1]{%
    \adjustbox{cfbox=#1}%
}

\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to remove all those spaces?
Thanks!

Comment: First something small. There is a small error in your MWE. There is a closing square bracket missing in the 6th includegraphics line.

Comment: That was an error formatting the text in the post.
I've used @AboAmmar solution and it worked great!

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.25cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{LightGray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}\arrayrulecolor{LightGray} \hline
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U}&\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U} \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U}&\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U} \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U}&\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U} \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U}&\includegraphics[width=13cm]{letter_U} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use simpler markup, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4,landscape]{article}

\setlength\textwidth{80cm}
\setlength\textheight{80cm}
\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\setlength\hoffset{-7cm}
\setlength\voffset{-2cm}

\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\definecolor{LightGray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\begin{document}

{
\offinterlineskip
\newcommand\zzzz{\fcolorbox{LightGray}{white}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{zzzz}}}

\zzzz\zzzz

\zzzz\zzzz

\zzzz\zzzz

\zzzz\zzzz

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code quite a bit, but I guess you don't mind all subfloats being in one figure environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[landscape,  margin=0.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

%\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.25}
\definecolor{LightGray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[1]{%
    \adjustbox{cfbox=#1}%
}

\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}\\[-4ex]%   
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}\\[-4ex]% 
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}\\[-4ex]%    
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
    \subfloat{\cfbox{LightGray}{\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Letter_U.png}}}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]